# How to set slider speed in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on wordpress site which is hardcoded. I could't find functions inside files. It is using owl carousel. I need to change speed of first carousel. I inspected this code in HTML.

```
<div id="owl-carousel-257654226" class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-jumbo owl-theme" data-singleitem="true" data-autoplay="10000" data-stoponhover="true" data-pagination="false" data-navigation="true" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">.....</div>
```

So data-autoplay is set to 10000, I guess I need it to be 5000. Because I want to slider change on 5s.

Can this be done i jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You have to update you Owl carousel call...something like this.

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:50000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true
});
```

or in case of data attr, try doing

```
var autoplay = $(this).data('autoplay','5000');
$(this).owlCarousel({
        autoplay: autoplay
 });
```

Ref:https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

Thanks !

Comment: I found this answer, but I could't find this call. Do you know in which file this should be?

Comment: Normally it will be in main js file...like site.js or main.js...if you are using chrome browser, try ctrl+shift+f and serach for the owl keyword...this will show in which file the call is..